# API in Java for STEP (p21) - to create STEP compliant files

Tags: java, cad, step

I'm interested in writing Java to automate the creation of 3D STEP files (CAD format).

There seems to be something for C++ (https://github.com/stepcode/stepcode).  There seem to be Java implementations of 3D CAD software (http://brlcad.org/).

However, I don't see an API / Package / Class Library anywhere to build STEP files using Java.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSDAI is a java API for STEP files and is licensed AGPL.

www.jsdai.net

Comment: Can I generate 3D model using JSDAI?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate 3D model"?

Comment: We can draw 3D shape using STEP file. There are many desktop version software available in the market. But I want to draw 3D model in WEB. That only possible if I read step data and draw model from this file.

Comment: There are many web (browser-only) viewers for 3D models in STEP files, such as GrabCAD.   If you want to see example source code, look at pythonocc.org.

Answer (score 0):

[BIMserver](https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMserver) and its friends in Open Source BIM](https://github.com/opensourceBIM) can easily handle this problem without writing a single line of code.